# Inheritance and Static Nested Java Classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm modeling something in Java and using a Builder pattern.  In a number of cases, some common members are defined in a parent, with additional members on children that inherit from the parent.  An example is as follows:

```
public class Parent {
    private Integer age;

    static class ParentBuilder {
        private Integer age;

        public ParentBuilder age(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    private Integer height;

    static class ChildBuilder extends Parent.ParentBuilder {
        private Integer height;

        public ChildBuilder height(Integer height) {
            this.height = height;
            return this;
        }

        public Child build() {
            return new Child(this);
        }
    }

    public static ChildBuilder builder() {
        return new ChildBuilder();
    }

    public Child(ChildBuilder b) {
        this.height = b.height;
    }
}
```

If I try to do something like

```
Child child = Child.builder()
    .age(18)
    .height(150)
    .build();
```

I get an error trying to compile:

```
Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        .height(150)
        ^
symbol:   method height(int)
location: class ParentBuilder
```

If I remove `.height(150)` I then get the same error on `.build()`.  It seems I have a fundamental misunderstanding of inheritance with static nested classes.

Why, when `Child.builder()` returns a `ChildBuilder`, is the compiler complaining about the method not being in `ParentBuilder`?  Is there a way to make this work as I'm attempting to, leveraging inheritance together with this Builder pattern to allow common members to be defined in the parent and others on the child?

Comment: It is `age` that returns a `ParentBuilder`, hence why there is a complation error trying to invoke `height`. Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086417/builder-pattern-and-inheritance or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164375/subclassing-a-java-builder-class

Comment: I would only use `Integer` instead of `int` if a) the value could be `null` or b) you had no choice

Comment: There are no [tag:inner-classes] here, only static nested classes, which are not inner by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work with generics

```
static class ParentBuilder<B extends ParentBuilder<B>> {
    public B age(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
        return (B) this;
    }
}

static class ChildBuilder extends Parent.ParentBuilder<ChildBuilder> {
    private Integer height;

    public ChildBuilder height(Integer height) {
        this.height = height;
        return this;
    }

    public Child build() {
        return new Child(this);
    }
}
```

This way `age` will return a `ChildBuilder` for a `ChildBuilder`

Comment: Thanks, coupled with @Tunaki's link I think I've got it.  Do need to cast `this` to (B) or use the `getThis()` pattern however.

Comment: @razor yes. You do need a cast. Updated the answer.