# POJO multiple-hierarchy Builder

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I'm trying to achieve a hierarchy of builder with more than 3 levels.

Something like:

```
  public abstract class ElementBuilder  {
    protected String name;

    public ElementBuilder setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
  }

  public abstract class OperationBuilder extends ElementBuilder {
     protected String attribute;

     public OperationBuilder setName(String attribute) {
         this.attribute = attribute;
         return this;
     }
  }



 public abstract class FilterBuilder extends OperationBuilder {
     ....
 }
```

The problem is that when I call an operation of the super class it's returning a builder of the that class. I don't want to duplicate the setter method in each child, cause it maybe contain some logic.

I tried using generics but I could not achieve it in a clean way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subclassing a Java Builder class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164375/subclassing-a-java-builder-class)

Comment: I dont want to cast the retuned Builder since this throw a warning.

Comment: You can avoid the cast with the "getThis" trick explained here: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206

Comment: I could do that, but I want to be able to build all the components, that way I will only be able to buld final child elements. :s

Comment: But it doesn't make sense. If all the builders are abstract, you can't build them. You need to build the child.

Comment: I want to build the child and the parent. Operation and Processor in this case.