# cast to Type in java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am new to generics and was looking at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17165079/1632141

It works perfectly, however I couldn't understand how this part of the code works.

```
 public T calories(int val) {
     calories = val;
     return (T) this;
 }
```

in the inner class of the `NutritionFacts`.

How does the cast work here? I was expecting `java.lang.ClassCastException` here, since we are casting a pure superclass object to subclass.

Comment: What do you mean, "pure superclass object"?  `this` always ends up being of type `T` anyway.

Comment: The code runs in the context of `public static class (GMOFacts.)Builder extends NutritionFacts.Builder<(GMOFacts.)Builder>`. `T` is therefore the builder's own type which makes it a legal cast. Also `this` is not of the superclass type, even though the code is declared in the superclass. `this` is always the concrete runtime (subclass) type.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Not true. It's possible for `this` to not be of type `T`.

Comment: @zapl: It's possible for `this` to not be a `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there's a problem with that answer:

```
public static class Builder<T extends Builder> {...
```

The type `T` is a *raw* type. It should be:

```
public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {...
```

which is called a *self referencing* type, because it's extending itself.

It's typically used like this:

```
public class SubBuilder extends Builder<SubBuilder> {...
```

in which case, the type is the type of the subclass itself.

You could code another subclass of Builder as the type, but that wouldn't be particularly useful.

Comment: I meant to say `T` is the type of the *subtype* itself

Comment: `T` does not have to be the type of the subclass itself

Answer (score -1):

You're not casting superclass object to subclass there. For `GMOFacts.Builder` object, the `calories` method would be type erased to something like this:

```
public GMOFacts.Builder calories(int val) {
        calories = val;
        return (GMOFacts.Builder) this;
    }
```

And `this` reference points to `GMOFacts.Builder` object anyways, so it's a valid type cast.

Comment: Just because the type-erased code is valid does not mean the the generic method is type-safe.

Comment: @newacct Sorry, I didn't understand. You talking about this particular method, or all generic methods in general? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Like I can write a method `<T> T foo(Object x) { return (T)x; }` which would also have a valid cast when erased, but is clearly not type-safe. The fact that the erased code of the method itself does not contain a cast that can fail does not mean that the generic method is type-safe, because the generic return type causes casts to be inserted in the calling code to cast the result, and that can fail.

Comment: @newacct I do understand that, but the erased method I gave is in context of the code in the linked answer.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to address with this answer. If you are trying to say that there will be no `ClassCastException` in this method specifically, then yes. But the generic cast can cause a `ClassCastException` in code outside the method.

Comment: @newacct Of course I'm talking about this particular case. That is what the question is about. And yes, unsafe generic casting can result in `ClassCastException`, and that I'm aware of. Here it was specifically for the question linked.

Comment: No, I am talking about this particular case too. The cast *is* unsafe and *can* cause a `ClassCastException` under certain circumstances, just not inside the method.

Comment: @newacct Well, it would result in `ClassCastException`, if the generic subclass, type parameter doesn't has `Builder<T>` as supertype. But then that would be different point altogether. This is the way we implement a generic builder pattern, and person do have to be careful in doing type-cast. Anyways, let's leave the discussion here only.

Comment: You mean if the subclass doesn't have `T` as a supertype? Yes, that's my point.