# Is there a generics notation so a TypeScript superclass method can return a subclass-compatible type?

Tags: typescript, generics

Here's the kind of situation I'm talking about:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(public n: number) {}

  get value(): number { return this.n; }

  addTwo(): Foo {
    this.n += 2;
    return this;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  // Can I avoid the code below, and type addTwo() in a way
  //   that returns type Bar for a Bar instance?
  //
  // addTwo(): Bar {
  //   return super.addTwo() as Bar;
  // }

  addThree(): Bar {
    this.n += 3;
    return this;
  }
}

const baz: Bar = new Bar(7).addTwo().addThree();
```

For the last line I get this error:

[image: error message]

I can't find any sort of notation that refers to the type of `this` that does the job. I'd like for the `addTwo()` method to be consider as returning type `Bar` when the instance accessing the method is itself type `Bar`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending builder in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204129/extending-builder-in-typescript)

Comment: @Stanislas, afraid not. That still shows the need for the subclass to have its own override of each method that returns the subclass's type.

Comment: Not a solution to your specific problem, but this project might be intresting to you: https://github.com/willryan/factory.ts#combining-factories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Polymorphic this types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types)

> A polymorphic this type represents a type that is the subtype of the containing class or interface. This is called F-bounded polymorphism, a lot of people know it as the fluent API pattern. This makes hierarchical fluent interfaces much easier to express, for example.

```
class Foo {
  constructor(public n: number) {}

  get value(): number { return this.n; }

  addTwo(): this {
    this.n += 2;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Anything where the word “this” is important to the question or the answer is almost impossible to find via Google 