# Java generics somewhat complex statement?

Tags: java, generics

```
public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {

    private int calories = 0;

    public Builder() {}

    public T calories(int val) {
        calories = val;
        return (T) this;
    }

    public NutritionFacts build() { return new NutritionFacts(this); }
}
```

From this code snippet, what does the first line do, `public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>`? Is there a recursion here?

Comment: Take a look into the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164375/subclassing-a-java-builder-class)

Comment: Yeah. I copied the snippet from the link you sent me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply means that the type of `T` must be a class that `extends Builder`. See this example:

```
public class ABuilder extends Builder<ABuilder> {

}
```

This construct is commonly seen when using the *builder pattern*, because it allows a super class to return an instance of the subclass so that subclass methods may still be used. From the example you've shown:

```
public T calories(int val) {
    calories = val;
    return (T) this;
}
```

Will allow that this code snippet works:

```
NutritionFacts nf = new ABuilder()
    .specificMethodForABuilder()        // returns ABuilder
    .calories(3)                        // returns also ABuilder
    .anotherSpecificMethodForABuilder() // returns again ABuilder
    .build();
```

The same would not work if the `calories()` method would've been declared like this (and the builder without a generic `T`):

```
public Builder calories(int val) {
    calories = val;
    return this;
}
```

You would get a compilation error if you tried this:

```
NutritionFacts nf = new ABuilder()
    .specificMethodForABuilder()        // returns ABuilder
    .calories(3)                        // returns only Builder
    .anotherSpecificMethodForABuilder() // unknown method
    .build();
```

Comment: `(T) this` is not type safe. The recursive bound does not help with this. The recursive bound is useful for other things.