# Extending Builder Class

Tags: java, android, builder, builder-pattern

I want to implement a design pattern where I setup a base builder class (BaseBuilder.java) that several other builder classes extend.

The base builder class is abstract, and it contains values that are common to the other builders. Each builder shares some common elements and also has unique elements.

BaseBuilder Class Example-

```
public class BaseBuilder {

    private final String key;
    private final String token;

    public BaseBuilder(Builder<?> builder) {
        this.key = builder.key;
        this.token = builder.token;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Builder {" +
            ", key='" + key + '\'' +
            ", token='" + token + '\'' +
            '}';
    }

    public abstract static class Builder<T extends Builder <T>> {

        private String key;
        private String token;

        public Builder setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setToken(String token) {
            this.token = token;
            return this;
        }

        public BaseBuilder build() {
            return new BaseBuilder(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to extend this BaseBuilder for other builders e.g. RedCar.

```
public class RedCar extends BaseBuilder {

    private final String redWheelCaps;

    public RedCar(RedCardBuilder builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.redWheelCaps = builder.redWheelCaps;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Red Car Builder {" +
            ", redWheelCaps='" + redWheelCaps + '\'' +
            '}';
    }

    public static class RedCardBuilder extends BaseBuilder<RedCardBuilder> {

        private String redWheelCaps;

        public RedCardBuilder setRedWheelCaps(String redWheelCaps) {
            this.redWheelCaps = redWheelCaps;
            return this;
        }


        public RedCar build() {
            return new RedCar(this);
        }
    }
}
```

When attempting to use this builder, I am having issues trying to achieve the following results.

```
// this is ideally what I want to achieve
// there is an error because I am not creating a BaseBuilder object
RedCar redCar = new RedCar.RedCarBuilder()
    .setKey("key")
    .setToken("token")
    .setRedWheelCaps("redCaps")
    .build();
```

The above does not work. I am being prompted that I have to use the BaseBuilder. So I updated my code to the following:

```
// this works good, but the order of my set values causes an error
BaseBuilder redCar = new RedCar.RedCarBuilder()
    .setKey("key")
    .setToken("token")
    .setRedWheelCaps("redCaps")
    .build();
```

I was forced to use Polymorphism. Which is fine, however, I still had an error until I rearranged how I set the values. For some reason, I have to set the values of RedCar first, before I can set the values of BaseBuilder. Otherwise I receive the error, "cannot resolve method". So I rearranged my set values to remove all errors.

```
// no errors at all. This works fine but is not what I was expecting
BaseBuilder redCar = new RedCar.RedCarBuilder()
    .setRedWheelCaps("redCaps")
    .setKey("key")
    .setToken("token")
    .build();
```

How can I fix my setup so that I can inherit and set values without having to conform to a specific order? And is there anyway of accomplishing what I am trying to do without having to use Polymorphism? Do I have the correct pattern idea? Thanks!

EDIT:
More information is that I can achieve what I am seeking so long that I omit the setters from BaseBuilder. So, the following is OK.

```
RedCar redCar = new RedCar.RedCarBuilder()
    .setRedWheelCaps("redCaps")
    .build();
```

How come it seems like I am unable to inherit the setters from my BaseBuilder?

Comment: this might be what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164375/subclassing-a-java-builder-class

Comment: That is the same issue that I have. The solution is exactly my setup. It does not address my above concerns. Any specific code examples you can demonstrate that will address my concerns?

Comment: @Pawel That post you linked did help. I was able to resolve my issue. The answer wasn't the accepted answer, it was the one posted by Q23. He based his response on the following post which worked like a charm! http://egalluzzo.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-inheritance-with-fluent.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the cleanest way to do what you want is to parameterize both the target type and the builder type. Then I create three builder types for each level of my type hierarchy: an interface, an abstract class, and a final class. Sounds like a lot of work? Welcome to Java generics.

I've used Lombok annotations to reduce the amount of extra typing. Here's your base class, and its builders:

```
@Getter
public class Rabbit {

    private final String sex;
    private final String name;

    public static Builder<?,?> builder() {
        return new BuilderImpl();
    }

    protected Rabbit(String sex, String name) {
        this.sex = sex;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public interface Builder<T extends Rabbit, B extends Builder<T,B>> {
        B sex(String value);
        B name(String value);
        T build();
    }

    @Getter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    protected static abstract class BaseBuilder<T extends Rabbit, B extends BaseBuilder<T,B>>
            implements Builder<T,B> {

        protected String sex;
        protected String name;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public B sex(String sex)
        {
            this.sex = sex;
            return (B) this;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public B name(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            return (B) this;
        }
    }

    private static final class BuilderImpl
            extends BaseBuilder<Rabbit,BuilderImpl> {

        public Rabbit build()
        {
            return new Rabbit(getSex(), getName());
        }
    }
}
```

And here's your extended class, and its builders:

```
@Getter
public class Lop extends Rabbit {

    private final float earLength;
    private final String furColor;

    public static Builder<?,?> builder() {
        return new BuilderImpl();
    }

    protected Lop(String sex, String name, float earLength, String furColor) {
        super(sex, name);
        this.earLength = earLength;
        this.furColor = furColor;
    }

    public interface Builder<T extends Lop, B extends Builder<T,B>>
            extends Rabbit.Builder<T,B> {
        public B earLength(float value);
        public B furColor(String value);
    }

    @Getter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    protected static abstract class BaseBuilder<T extends Lop, B extends BaseBuilder<T,B>>
            extends Rabbit.BaseBuilder<T,B>
            implements Builder<T,B> {

        private float earLength;
        private String furColor;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public B earLength(float value) {
            this.earLength = value;
            return (B) this;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public B furColor(String value) {
            this.furColor = value;
            return (B) this;
        }
    }

    private static final class BuilderImpl
            extends BaseBuilder<Lop,BuilderImpl> {

        public Lop build()
        {
            return new Lop(getSex(), getName(), getEarLength(), getFurColor());
        }
    }
}
```

And a test confirms that it all works:

```
public class RabbitTest {

    @Test
    public void rabbitTest() {
        Lop herman = Lop.builder().furColor("Gray").name("Herman").sex("male").earLength(4.6f).build();
        Assert.assertEquals("Herman", herman.getName());
    }
}
```