# Subclassing a subclass of a (generic) builder

Tags: java, generics, builder

I'm trying to implement a builder object with multi-level inheritance. I took some inspiration from [Subclassing a Java Builder class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164375/subclassing-a-java-builder-class) and this is my (simplified) code:

```java
public class StackOverflow {
    public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {
        public Builder() {}

        public T doA() {
            System.out.println("A");
            return (T) this;
        }
    }

    public static class BuilderSubclass <T extends BuilderSubclass<T>> 
            extends Builder<BuilderSubclass<T>> {

        public BuilderSubclass() {}

        public T doB() {
            System.out.println("B");
            return (T) this;
        }
    }

    public static class BuilderSubclassSubclass
            extends BuilderSubclass<BuilderSubclassSubclass> {

        public BuilderSubclassSubclass() {}

        public BuilderSubclassSubclass doC() {
            System.out.println("C");
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like do something like this: 
`new StackOverflow.BuilderSubclassSubclass().doA().doC().doB()`

However, when I call `new StackOverflow.BuilderSubclassSubclass().doA()`, the returned object is not a `BuilderSubclassSubclass` but a `BuilderSubclass<BuilderSubclassSubclass>`. I know why this is the case: `Builder`'s generic type is `BuilderSubclass<BuilderSubclassSubclass>` which is assigned in the class signature of `BuilderSubclass`.

Any ideas on how I can avoid this problem?

Update: I guess I could avoid using the builder pattern, and instead call the functions like this:

```java
StackOverflow.BuilderSubclassSubclass builder = new StackOverflow.BuilderSubclassSubclass();
builder.doA();
builder.doB();
builder.doC();
```

In which case the code becomes:

```java
public class StackOverflowBatchHelperFunctions {
    public static class Builder {

        public Builder() {
        }

        public void doA() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    public static class BuilderSubclass extends Builder {
        public BuilderSubclass() {
            super();
        }

        public void doB() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }

    public static class BuilderSubclassSubclass extends BuilderSubclass {
        public BuilderSubclassSubclass() {
            super();
        }

        public void doC() {
            System.out.println("C");
        }
    }
}
```

However I think this is less "pretty", so I would still love to see an answer to the initial problem.

Comment: @Lino Why not? Can you elaborate?

Comment: By the way, your `(T) this` casts are all unsafe. `this` is not guaranteed to be an instance of `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `public static class BuilderSubclass<T extends BuilderSubclass<T>> extends Builder<BuilderSubclass<T>>` with `public static class BuilderSubclass<T extends BuilderSubclass<T>> extends Builder<T>`.