# Subclassing a builder class giving me null when passing the builder from child to parent class

Tags: java

I'm following the implementation of subclassing a builder class from this stackoverflow answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17165079/11110509

I've been staring at my code for an hour now comparing it to the one in that answer. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly because the `builder` passed from my child class to my `parent` class is giving me null values.

My parent class:

```
public class BaseNft {

    private static final String TAG = "BaseNft";

    private final String itemName;
    private final String itemDescription;
    private final String ownerOf;
    private final String txHash;
    
    protected BaseNft(Builder<?> builder) {
        itemName = builder.itemName;
        itemDescription = builder.itemDescription;
        ownerOf = builder.ownerOf;
        txHash = builder.txHash;

        Log.d(TAG, "BaseNft: " + txHash); //Returns null
    }

    public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {
        private String itemName;
        private String itemDescription;
        private String ownerOf;
        private String txHash;
        
        public T itemName(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            return (T) this;
        }

        public T itemDescription(String itemDescription) {
            this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
            return (T) this;
        }

        public T ownerOf(String ownerOf) {
            this.ownerOf = ownerOf;
            return (T) this;
        }

        public T txHash(String txHash) {
            this.txHash = txHash;
            return (T) this;
        }

        
        public BaseNft build() {
            return new BaseNft(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My child class:

```
public class Card extends BaseNft {

    protected Card(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
    }

    public static class Builder extends BaseNft.Builder<Builder> {
        private String cardName;
        private String cardDescription;
        private String ownerOf;
        private String txHash;

        public Builder itemName(String itemName) {
            this.cardName = itemName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder itemDescription(String itemDescription) {
            this.cardDescription = itemDescription;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder ownerOf(String ownerOf) {
            this.ownerOf = ownerOf;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder txHash(String txHash) {
            this.txHash = txHash;
            return this;
        }

        public Card build() {
            return new Card(this);
        }
    }

}
```

```
Card card = new Card.Builder()
                .itemName("name")
                .itemDescription("description")
                .ownerOf("owner name")
                .txHash("test txhash")
                .build();
```

I've traced the card creation with logs and in the `build()` method for my child class

```
public Card build() {
    //successfully returns values
    return new Card(this);
}
```

it successfully returns the name, description, owner, and txhash.
But in the parent class's constructor `BaseNft` they return null. I can't figure out why. Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Don't declare in subclass fields with same name as in superclass. This way you are creating separate fields but since you are giving them same name you are *shadowing* already existing fields. Anyway at `Log.d(TAG, "BaseNft: " + txHash); //Returns null` you are printing value of `txHash` declared in superclas, but in subclass you *overrode* setter to initialize *separate* `txHash` field (declared in subclass builder). So don't declare  same fields if they ware already declared in superclass. And don't override setters for those fields.

Comment: code is not calling the methods from parent class, ergo the fields of parent class are not being set. (an (indirect) consequence of having two fields for same 8attribute* as already written in previous comment) A subclass already includes the fields of the parent class(es) no *need* to repeat these.

Comment: @Pshemo, user16320675 That fixed it. Honestly I wouldn't have figured it out by myself. Thank you.